# Duplicate existing element in xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, clone

Please I would like to clone element **prijemkaItem** from this xml:

[image]

The element prijemkaItem is got by this function:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("input.xml");            
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("input.xml");

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:

                    if (reader.Name == "pri:prijemkaItem")
                        elementPrijemkaItem = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;

                    break;
            }
        }
        reader.Close()
```

I would like to put this element behind itself. Please any idea, how can I do this?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: "Put the element behind itself" - Could you clarify this line? Also, I cannot even see your xml. Could you instead copy and paste the xml to the question? (you can add more info to your question by clicking the "edit" button). You don't have do copy all of the xml, just the nodes to understand the xml structure.

Comment: I had problems to copy all xml to code block. So I made this small xml printscreen. But now it is solved by Fuex bellow. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for simplicity that your Xml structure is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dat:dataPack xmlns:dat="datNamespace">
  <dat:dataPackItem>
    <pri:prijemka xmlns:pri="priNamespace">
      <othernode></othernode>
    </pri:prijemka>
  </dat:dataPackItem>
</dat:dataPack>
```

If you want to duplicate the `pri:prijemka` node you can use **Linq to Xml**:

```
//using System.Xml.Linq;

//load the xml file
Document doc = XDocument.Load( "D:\\input.xml" );
//get the "dat" namespace 
var datNamespace = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix( "dat" );

//get "dat:dataPackItem" node
var dataPackItemNode = doc.Root.Element( datNamespace + "dataPackItem" );
//since you don't know the "pri" namespace you can do:
var prijemkaNode = dataPackItemNode.Descendants( )
                       .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "prijemka")
                       .FirstOrDefault();

//add it to the "dat:dataPackItem" node
dataPackItemNode.Add( prijemkaNode );
//save the xml file
doc.Save( "D:\\input.xml" );
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dat:dataPack xmlns:dat="datNamespace">
  <dat:dataPackItem>
    <pri:prijemka xmlns:pri="priNamespace">
      <othernode></othernode>
    </pri:prijemka>
    <pri:prijemka xmlns:pri="priNamespace">
      <othernode></othernode>
    </pri:prijemka>
  </dat:dataPackItem>
</dat:dataPack>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it worked you, please consider accepting the answer :) and upvote it if you want. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, I have already tried to vote, but I need to have reputation at least 15, but have just 13. but no worries when I will have, I will vote..